# Angstrom not working

Tags: units

Using `\AA` for angstrom is not working for me. When I write 1 `\AA` all I get is  `2 (r)A` in the output. I have tried putting the curly brackets around it `{\AA}` but still no success. I do not know why. I have even tried changing the fonts I am using. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`\AA` is a text command which essentially becomes `\r{A}`; `\r` is the command producing the "ring accent" and is invalid in math mode. Here's a way:

```
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\mbox{\normalfont\AA}}
```

If the unit must be used also in subscripts or superscripts,

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % or simply amstext
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\text{\normalfont\AA}}
```

Following daleif suggestion, a more compact version would be

```
\usepackage{amsmath} % or simply amstext
\newcommand{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}
```

(**amsmath** is necessary, otherwise `\textup` doesn't change sizes in subscripts).

However, the best practice when dealing with units is to use **siunitx** as suggested by quinmars. The macros `\si` and `\SI` made available by it provide the correct spacing.

Answer (score 47):

I'd suggest to use the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package. If you want a quantity, use:

```
The lattice constant $a = \SI{2.0}{\angstrom}$ is ...
```

if you only need the unit, use:

```
Atomic distances are measured in \si{\angstrom}.
```

Comment: And you can get the real ångström character with the `lmodern` package and `\sisetup{text-angstrom={Å},math-angstrom={\text{Å}}}` with UTF-8 input.

Comment: Version 3 of the siunitx package (released on 2021-05-18) has removed `\angstrom`. It can be re-added manually with `\DeclareSIUnit{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}` in the preamble (using the suggestion from [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24278/237491)).

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. I think Angstrom is an often used and important unit.

Answer (score 6):

@egreg answer is correct but in the community is hard to convince others (reluctant-TeX) collaborators to use `\mbox{\normalfont\AA}` or `\text{\normalfont\AA}` to write Angstrom units. At best one can hope that they use `\mathrm{\AA}` (so Angstrom doesn't appear as italic in math formulas). They are just too used to write `\AA`.

What I suggest is this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\oldAA\AA
\renewcommand{\AA}{\text{\normalfont\oldAA}}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 1):

What caused this problem for me is that I redefined the `\r` command.
That is, I had a

```
\renewcommand{\r}
```

in my preamble. If this is the case, change the name of the command you called `\r` to something else.