# How to put Angstrom

Tags: units

Can anyone tell how to put the capital Angstrom to express units. I have been looking for a package but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: `\AA` is not OK?

Comment: `\AA` is invalid in math mode. In math mode, put it in `\text{}` as `\(\text{\AA}\)`, or see some solutions at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24255/140604)

Comment: @ydhhat If you use `\text`, the formatting of the surrounding text will bleed through to math mode. This most often happens with italics in theorem statements. You probably would want `\textnormal` to rest the formatting, or `\textup` if you want to clear italics/small caps but use bold math in a header. Or, use `siunitx`.

Answer (score 21):

The excellent [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package is there for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\si{\angstrom}

\SI{1}{\angstrom}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `\angstrom` has been deprecated in `siunitx` from version 2 to 3 (as it is not an official SI unit), it has to be defined as a custom unit, examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24255/angstrom-not-working
Also, `\SI` has been replaced by `\qty{}` commands.

Comment: `\DeclareSIUnit{\angstrom}{\textup{\AA}}`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, simply typing

```
\r{A}
```

works fine! Also, it seems that it does not need any package, not even the ams packages, which is a bit strange).

P.S.: I do not have the unitx package installed (I want to install it, but for the moment to do not know how to install it on miktex..)

Comment: `\r{A}` is invalid in math mode. In math mode, put it in `\text{}` as `\(\text{\r{A}}\)`, or see some solutions at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24255/140604)

Comment: Doesn't work in MathJax for example.

Comment: @user1271772 mathjax has notthing to do with LaTeX other than it knows a limited math syntax

Comment: @daleif that is false. Not only does it know a limited math syntax, it also knows a limited LaTeX syntax. So it doesn't have "nothing" to do with LaTeX other than that.

Comment: Not so good. does not typeset so well

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that works in both text and math mode is

```
\textup{~\AA}
```

This always sets the unit upright, but makes it bold if you use it in a header.  It also avoids line breaking between a quantity and its unit. In practice, you’d end up defining a macro for this that’s no simpler than `\qty` from `siunitx`.

Comment: But the spacing is wrong, that is a word space it should be a small space: `\,`